# How to compile the multithread code with gcc

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-10.04

I have seen the given two makefiles as follows:

```
all: thread1 thread2 thread3

CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/nptl -D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread

clean:
    rm -f thread1 thread2 thread3

######################

all: thread1 thread2 thread3

CFLAGS=-D_REENTRANT
LDFLAGS=-lpthread

clean:
    rm -f thread1 thread2 thread3
```

Without using makefile, what is the correct command line to compile the thread1.c with gcc?

> gcc -o thread1
>   CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/nptl
>   -D_REENTRANT LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread thread1.c

Comment: What are you trying to ask?  Those two makefiles will cause different commands to get run.

Comment: I don't want to use these makefile to compile all the source codes and would like to just compile the code one by one through gcc commandline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc: Do I need -D_REENTRANT with pthreads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads)

Comment: But which set of flags do you need to pass?  Do you need the `-I` and `-L` flags or not?  That's not something anyone here can answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code don't have external dependencies beyond pthread:

```
gcc thread1.c -o thread1 -D_REENTRANT -lpthread
```

[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601753/reentrant-flag-in-pthreads/2602822#2602822):

> Defining _REENTRANT causes the compiler to use thread safe (i.e. re-entrant) versions of several functions in the C library.

Comment: Do you think both CFLAGS=-D_REENTRANT and LDFLAGS=-lpthread are not necessary?

Comment: I think the code uses nptl. From the book "In multithreaded programs, you tell the compiler that you need this feature by defining the _REENTRANT
macro before any #include lines in your program." But the attached source code thread1.c doesn't include the _REENTRANT, so I wonder what I should do.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is answered here

[gcc: Do I need -D_REENTRANT with pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads)

Essentially all you need is

`gcc thread1.c -o thread1 -pthread`

and gcc will handle all the defines for you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost:

```
gcc -o thread1 -I/usr/include/nptl -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/lib/nptl thread1.c -lpthread
```

The `*FLAGS` variables contain the arguments that are passed to the compiler and linker invocartion, respectively. (In your case you're compiling and linking in one go.) Make sure to add libraries *after* your own object files.

Answer (score 1):

Those two makefiles will generate two different sets of command-line arguments.  You could check it yourself just by running `make`:

```
$ make -f makefile1
cc -I/usr/include/nptl -D_REENTRANT  -L/usr/lib/nptl -lpthread  thread1.c   -o thread1
$ make -f makefile2
cc -D_REENTRANT  -lpthread  thread1.c   -o thread1
```

Choose your favourite.

Comment: The original makefile compiles all source code under the directory. So I want to avoid running it by using gcc command-line.

Comment: @q0987 - but `make` already shows you the command line.  Just copy/paste it from the output.