# Compiling multithread code with Code::Blocks GNU compiler

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, compilation

### The error

I am trying to use ***std::thread*** but I have this error when I try to run it.

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
>
> what(): Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not
> permitted
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

### Result of my research

There are a **lot** of questions about it and every answer say similar things :
I have to build with "-pthread" or "-lpthread". Some also say to add "-Wl,--no-as-needed".

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587245/how-to-compile-the-multithread-code-with-gcc) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274032/c-threads-stdsystem-error-operation-not-permitted) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649828/what-is-the-correct-link-options-to-use-stdthread-in-gcc-under-linux) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463602/compiling-multithread-code-with-g) [Link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/103862/)

I tried a lot of things but none worked.

### Details

I am compiling with **Code::Blocks** 12.11, **GNU GCC** Compiler on **Lubuntu**.
In the compiler settings menu, compiler flags I have checked

> "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

and under other options I wrote what the answer was saying, here is an example

```
-pthread
-Wl,--no-as-needed
```

Here is the build log I have (I am not sure if it is important)

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed  -std=c++11   -I../DeskManagerDll -I/usr/include/X11/extensions -I/usr/include/X11  -c /home/julien/Documents/test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -L/home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll -L-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib  -lX11 -lXext -lpthread -Wl,--no-as-needed  /home/julien/Documents/DeskManagerDll/bin/Debug/libDeskManagerDll.so 
Output size is 187,15 KB
```

### My question

What am I doing wrong ? What did I miss ?

### Edit

I made a very simple program to exclude any other problem.

```
#include <thread>

void test()
{
    
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thread_fct (test);
    return 0;
}
```

The build log with this program:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed  -std=c++11    -c /home/julien/Documents/test/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/test obj/Debug/main.o
```

**I still have the exact same error**. I really don't know what to try. **Do you have any idea ?**

Comment: Try adding `-pthread` to the `.so` compilation as well.

Comment: I don't see how to do that, do you know what I should google to find where I can modify it ? I am a bit lost in all of this

Comment: In your second `g++` line, add `-pthread` (and possibly remove `-lpthread`, `-pthread` should do that for you.)

Comment: It has been automaticaly generated by code::blocks. I can modify it through the options but the "other option" field changes the first line.

Comment: IMO it's a bit unexpected for the standard library to start overloading `EPERM` to mean something pretty different.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Is it the error or my compiler settings that are unexpected ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first problem is that `-lpthread` is a linker option, so it belongs on the linker line (the second command) rather than the compilation line.  (Note that the order of the parameters can matter; I got it to work by putting `-lpthread` on **last**.  I also tried using `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, which did appear to work and was also less sensitive to where it was put on the linker line.  But again, it's a *linker* option, not a *compile* option.)

After fixing that, I was able to get your program to compile and run, but it exited with a different exception: `terminate called without an active exception`.  To fix this problem, call `thread_fct.join();` in `main()`.  (All threads must be joined, detached, or moved-from before they go out of scope, or your program will abort.)

Answer (score 2):

The way that was useful for me for code::blocks:

1. Project -> Build options -> Have g++ follow C++11 ISO ... [-std=c+11] (select checkbox)
2. Project -> Build options -> Linker settings -> Other linker options add there

   ```
   -Wl,--no-as-needed
   -pthread
   ```