# Why do we write -D_REENTRANT while compiling C code using threads

Tags: gcc

We write this statement when we are compiling a C program that has threads implemented in them.
I could not understand why we use -D_REENTRANT here.
e.g `gcc t1.c -lpthread -D_REENTRANT`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the \_REENTRANT flag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601753/what-is-the-reentrant-flag)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to write it. But it is recommended.

`Defining _REENTRANT` causes the compiler to use thread safe (i.e. re-entrant) versions of several functions in the C library.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, the recommended way to compile with threads in GCC is using the `-pthread` option. It is equivalent to `-lpthread -D_REENTRANT` so you have actually no problem.

The flags do the following:

- `-lpthread` instructs the linker to use the appropriate library versions for thread compatibility.
- `-D_REENTRANT` tells the compiler to use the declarations (functions, types, ...) necessary for thread usage.

Comment: For GCC 6 and earlier, -pthread was a machine-specific option for RS/6000 and PowerPC, as well as Solaris 2. Since GCC 7, -pthread has been generalised for all platforms. (GCC 7 was released in May 2017, and this answer was written over 3 year before that.)

Answer (score 6):

Compilers like `gcc` use `-D` `name` to predefine `name` as a macro with definition `1`.

In the program source code and header files, you will see compiler directives that check for `_REENTRANT` and does something when this macro is `true` or `1`.

If this macro is not passed to the compiler, then the compiler directive `_REENTRANT` would be `false` or `0`.

Take this example from /usr/include/features.h.

```
#if defined _REENTRANT || defined _THREAD_SAFE
# define __USE_REENTRANT    1
#endif
```

You will see that it tells the compiler what to do if _REENTRANT is defined.

Finally, you have to link your code agains `pthread` library so you can use `pthread_*()` family like `pthread_create()`, `pthread_join()`.

When `-lpthread` is passed to the linker, the code gets linked with `libpthread.so`.