# How does the echo | g++ work in the following script

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Based on [gcc: Do I need -D_REENTRANT with pthreads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads)

```
> echo | g++          -E -dM -c - > singlethreaded
> echo | g++ -pthread -E -dM -c - > multithreaded
> diff singlethreaded multithreaded
39a40
> #define _REENTRANT 1
```

The author uses the above command to export the options used by the compiler.
I want to know why such a command works in detail:

```
> echo | g++ -E -dM -c - > singlethreaded
```

I understand the following parts:

```
> singlethread # means to redirect the results to the file singlethread
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-dM` option:

> Instead of the normal output, generate
>   a list of #define directives for all
>   the macros defined during the
>   execution of the preprocessor,
>   including predefined macros. This
>   gives you a way of finding out what is
>   predefined in your version of the
>   preprocessor.

The `-E` option:

> Stop after the preprocessing stage; do
>   not run the compiler proper. The
>   output is in the form of preprocessed
>   source code, which is sent to the
>   standard output.

The `-c` option causes the compiler to compile but not link.  This is superfluous with the -E option.

The solitary `-` tells the compiler to read its input from stdin.

Thus, the command echoes an empty stream to `stdout`, pipes that empty stream to `g++`, which then reads the empty stream but runs only the preprocessor, which has been told to ignore the input (empty) and output the complete list of defined preprocessor macros.

Comment: do you see there is '-' following the '-c'? '-' means ??

Comment: I missed that the first time, and mixed up `-c` -- I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`echo | g++ -` tells `g++` to compile `stdin` and passes in an empty program (a blank line from `echo`).  The `-E` option invokes only the preprocessor (it's similar to running `cpp` directly but with any macros automatically defined by `g++` present).  The `-dM` option is a debug flag which dumps out state inside the compiler at a particular step:

> ```
>        -dM
>        -fdump-rtl-mach
>            Dump after performing the machine dependent reorganization
>            pass, to file.155r.mach.
> ```

The purpose of all this is to discover what macros the compiler sets differently when you vary the command line parameter `-pthread` by comparing that dump output.