# What's the point of gcc's -pthread and -rdynamic option?

Tags: gcc

1. If I want to link with pthread, I can `-lpthread`,right?
2. I still don't see the reason to use `-rdynamic` after reading the manual..

Answer (score 3):

1. `-pthread` is shortcut for `-D_REENTRANT -lpthread`. On Linux. It is shortcut for whatever is appropriate on other platforms where the library may be called differently. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads).
2. Well, I think `-rdynamic` is explained quite well in the manual. It is needed if you want to have dynamic symbol information *in an executable*, which is useful for getting backtrace (in absence of debug information) and using `dlsym` to find symbols dynamically (e.g. GtkBuilder's autoconnect uses this).

Comment: @new_perl: You can use `dlsym` from shared library and/or plugin (which is shared library) to your heart's desire. It's only the rare case of using `dlsym` on the executable itself and there may be other options that imply exporting the symbols too.

Comment: Can you elaborate why GtkBuilder's autoconnect uses that?

Comment: @new_perl: It has XML with the widget declarations and it may include names of functions that should handle events (signals). And it uses `dlsym` to get the functions and connects them to the signals.