# Do I need to explicitly use `_r` suffix when using `-D_REENTRANT`?

Tags: c, multithreading, reentrancy

I'm writing an multithreaded application and I'm wondering about following:
When using `-D_REENTRANT` macro, do I need to explicitly use `_r` suffixed functions?

e.g. Shall I use `strtok_r` everywhere in the code or can I use `strtok` and make sure I pass `-D_REENTRANT` macro to the compiler?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875789/gcc-do-i-need-d-reentrant-with-pthreads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining `_REENTRANT` won't change the semantics of `strtok()`. You'll need to use `strtok_r()`.

Comment: In addition `-D_REENTRANT` is a no-op on any modern system.

Comment: thanks for the answer, @R.. can you please explain your comment a little bit more?

Comment: Inspecting `features.h` on a glibc-based system, `_REENTRANT` causes `__USE_REENTRANT` to be defined. The only place where `__USE_REENTRANT` is ever checked, however, is for `getlogin_r` in `unistd.h`, and it's also exposed if `__USE_POSIX199506` is defined, which is defined in the default features profile.

Comment: I don't have any data for other systems right off except to say that the practice of having different versions of functions when `_REENTRANT` is defined was an ancient hack from when threads were new and scary to unix. There's no good reason to do things that way now, and lots of good reasons not to (subtle bugs if it's omitted when compiling some files).